# Is HTTP Post blocked by Cloud9?

Tags: python, flask, cloud9-ide

I've been playing around with Python/Flask on Cloud9 ide. Pretty fun so far. But when I try to add a http post to my test project, Flask returns either a 403 or a 500. From what I can tell, when I attach data or send the POST method, the 'request' object is None. It doesn't make sense though. This is pretty straight forward and should work as far as I can tell. Here's the python:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request
@app.route('/test', methods = ['POST'])
def post():
    print ('started')
    print request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        something = request.get_json()
        print something
```

Flask is running correctly. I can hit a GET url, returning data just fine. I get an error when I land on 'print request' because request is None.

Thanks,

Comment: How are you attaching data to the post? Can you show an example?

Comment: I'm using Postman to test it. I tried it with form data and raw data, but the request is always None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here:

- You're getting a 500 error
- "something" is always None

The first problem is because you're not returning anything from your route function.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2014 15:08:59] "POST /test HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...snip...
  ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

You can remedy this by adding a return statement at the end of the function. Don't forget it needs to be a string.

```
@app.route('/hi', methods = ['POST'])
def post():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

The second problem isn't what it seems. I suspect that the object isn't None, but the function that returns the string representation returns None, so that's what gets printed. Try `print type(request)` to see this in action.

What I think you want access to is the `form` field. Here is a complete example:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/test', methods = ['POST'])
def post():
    print type(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.form
    return str(request.form)

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: the two gotchas here were 'Has to return a string'. I'm sure its documented, but I just didn't see it. And response.get_json() wasn't doing anything. But yes, what I wanted to see was indeed on request.form. Thanks a bunch!